# Domain-Driven Design: How to design relational aggregates with a dependency

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate

My domain is about Program Management. I have a Program (Aggregate Root) that must have a Customer (Aggregate Root). So I require a CustomerID when creating a new Program as I have read aggregates should only hold reference to other aggregates by reference.

Here are my business rules:

1. Customers can become active and inactive over time.
2. If a Customer is inactivated for some reason, all programs associated with that Customer should also be inactivated.
3. A Program cannot be activated if its Customer is inactive.

Rules #1 & #2 I have implemented. It's #3 that is stumping me.

I can think of 3 solutions:

1. Program holds reference to the Customer aggregate.
2. Introduce a domain service that checks if the Customer is active and pass it to Program.Activate(CustomerActiveCheckService service).
3. Have the application service look up the Customer and pass it to Program.Activate(Customer customer).

Which is the best solution?

**Update**

I see both points of view made by @ConstaninGALBENU and @plalx, and I want to suggest a compromise. Can I created a `CustomerStatusChecker` service? The method would have the following signature: `CustomerStatus CheckStatus(CustomerID id);` I could then pass `Program`the service like so: `Program.Activate(CustomerStatusChecker service);

Are there any problems with this design?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: it breaks the rule about not holding references to other aggregate instances. That rule ensures that only one Aggregate is modified in a transaction. If you need to modify multiple aggregates in a single transaction then your design is definitely wrong.

Solution 2: I really don't like injecting services inside aggregates. My aggregates are pure functions with no touching of the outside world  (I/O, repositories or the like).

Solution 3: is somehow equivalent to 1, even it is a temporary reference (`Program` could call command methods on `Customer` thus modifying `Customer` in the same transaction boundary as `Program`) .

My solution: make that check inside the Application service, before that call to `Program.activate ()` or pass a `customerStatus` to `Program.activate ()` and let `Program` aggregate decide if it throws an exception or emit events.

**Update:**

The idea is that you should pass only read-only/imutable data to `Program` AR to ensure that it does not modify other ARs in its transactional boundary. *Also, we should not make `Program` dependent on what it does not need, like the entire `Customer` AR*.

Also, if the architecture is event-driven then by listening to the right events emited by `Customer` you could keep the `Program` AR in sync: you make it "non activable" if not already activated or you deactivate it if it is activated already, using by example a `Saga`.

Comment: If passing a customerStatus, how do you ensure the correct customerStatus is passed?

Comment: I do not agree that solution #3 is equivalent to #1 as it is clear that the AR is not part of the boundary which is not with #1. Actually Vaughn Vernon recommended both (#2 and #3) in his IDDD book.

Comment: I'd say #5 could be to maintain a `canBeActivated` flag within `Program` which is kept up to date by listening to domain events such as `CustomerActivated` and `CustomerDeactivated`. I guess that is pretty much how you deactivate `Program` instances already?

Comment: @BrianGray the app service loads the *correct* customer by id from the repo then acces a `status` property. The idea is to pass a read-only value to `Program` so that it does not try to mutate other ARs

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU How do you ensure what? That `Program` doesn't mutate `Customer`? Well, it would be a hard thing to do by mistake and would almost have to be deliberate and I doubt programmers would deliberately introduce bugs. I could ask the same, how are you sure that the status the `Program` receives belongs to the right customer?

Comment: @plalx you should make the implicit explicit (an old DDD rule). Programmers do all kind of bad things unintentional. Good code, written for humans, not for machines, prevents the bugs from appearing in the first place. That is why `Values objects` are immutable: it is a indication that you should not mutate it. Write code like this even if you are the only ptogrammer as it helps you cognitive load, if your previous written code prevents you from modifying something then that is an indication that you shouldn't try.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Well, tell that to DDD veterans like Vaughn Vernon ;) I am well aware of the VO advantages, but I'm saying that it is extremely unlikely that a programmer would actually call mutating behavior such as `customer.changeAddress(new Address(...))` within `Program.activate` by mistake. For instance, check [this code](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_collaboration/src/main/java/com/saasovation/collaboration/domain/model/forum/Forum.java#L121) here from IDDD. Nothing prevents a programmer from calling other mutating behaviors on `post`.

Comment: There is no perfect solution, even in your case a programmer could just pass an arbitrary status to the `Program` by "mistake". The model should help avoiding mistakes, but it cannot always prevent them entirely.

Comment: @plalx I know these things from my experience and also from *veterans*. Anyway, "make the implicit explicit" beats any contradicting rule from IDDD

Comment: @plalx a programmer could delete all the code by mistake :| no, lets not go there. The correct customer status it is trivial to be passed correctly because of the naming of the parameter: "customerStatus"; if you want to be more explicit you could name it "customerIsActive"

Comment: @plalx also, if customerStatus is an instance of an enum-like class (or Value object) then your compiler will react instantly on your "mistake" if you pass something else

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU That's not what I'm saying. I meant that you could theorically hard-code `program.activate(CustomerStatus.DEACTIVATED)` even though that doesn't reflect in any way the state of the actual program's customer. However, I think we can safely assume that the right status will get passed by the application service just like we can probably assume that a programmer wouldn't call `customer.doSomething()` rather than accessing `customer.status()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138691/discussion-between-plalx-and-constantin-galbenu).

Answer (score 0):

> Which is the best solution?

There isn't a *best* solution; there are trade offs.

But one possible solution that is consistent with requirements #2 and #3 is that your existing model is wrong -- that Program entities are not isolated aggregates, but are part of the Customer entity, and therefore should be controlled by the same aggregate root.

Hints that this might be the case: that the life cycle of a Program fits within the life cycle of a Customer; that Programs don't normally migrate from one Customer to another, that there are limits to the count of active programs per customer.

Another possibility is that the requirements are "wrong".  One way of exploring this is to review whether active/inactive is a decision made by the model, or if it is a decision made somewhere else and *reported to* the model.  Another is to examine the cost to the business if this "rule" is violated.

If the model doesn't find out about the customer right away, or it is an inexpensive problem, then you probably have some room to detect the conflict and report it to a human, rather than trying to have the model do all of the work (See: Greg Young, [Stop Over Engineering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRr4xeMn1uU)).

In these cases, having the main code path take a good guess, and implementing an alternative path that operators can use fix the mistakes is fine.

In choosing between solution #2 and #3 (I don't like #1 at all), I encourage keeping I/O actions out of the model.  So unless you already have the latest version of the Customer in memory, I'm not fond of the domain service as a choice.  Passing in a copy of the customer state to the domain model keeps the I/O concerns in the application component, where they belong (see [Boundaries](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries), by Gary Bernhardt, for more on this idea).

Comment: I wouldn't be too precoccupied with the model being wrong here. Keep ARs small, as Vaugn Vernon recommends; business requirements may change and smaller ARs are better prepared for change.

Comment: The decision on design is based on a couple things. First, Program is responsible for maintaining Requirements that change over time. Second, if I make Customer the AR over Program, I'd have to follow the same logic for Employees. Then what do I do about a ParticipantRoster object that tracks which Employees are in which Programs?